# SonarQube: "Invoke method(s) only conditionally"

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube

Let's consider there is a class `Status` from a third party library which has implemented `toString()` method of their own as per below: -

```
public class Status<T> extends AttemptStatus<T> {

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Status{");
        sb.append("id=").append(this.id);
        sb.append(", startTime=").append(this.startTime);
        sb.append(", endTime=").append(this.endTime);
        .....
    }
}
```

I use this class in my code as per below: -

```
public class ABC {

private <T> T executeWithRetries(Callable<T> callable, RetryConfig conf) {
    Status<T> status = new CallExecutorBuilder()
            .config(conf)
            .afterFailedTryListener(s -> {
                    LOGGER.warn("Connection failed. Retrying.");
                    MetricsUtil.REDIS_RETRIES_METER.mark();
                    this.redis = createConnection();
            })
            .build()
            .execute(callable);
    LOGGER.info(status.toString());
    return status.getResult();
}
```

Now SonarQube complains about `Invoke method(s) only conditionally` on this sentence below:-

```
LOGGER.info(status.toString());
```

So if I remove `toString()` from above sentence then compiler complains as per below: -

```
 LOGGER.info(status);
```

`Cannot resolve method 'info(com.evanlennick.retry4j.Status<T>)'`

Should I wrap the `status` variable in `String.valueOf()`? but then it would not give me a desired toString() method output specified in the `Status` class. Any solution?

Comment: What is `LOGGER`? The answers will depend on what other methods are available in your logging class. Also, the complaint from sonarqube should have a link to an example of how it preferred you wrote the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

`LOGGER.info("{}",status);`